# SQL Server 2000 > EXECUTE AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Hey all.  Could someone tell me how to elevate the execution of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2000?  I've tried using EXECUTE AS, but that was added in SQL SERVER 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OPENQUERY as a loopback to itself

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (ThisServer, 'EXEC db.dbo.MyProc')

Your options are very limited on SQL Server 2000

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your timely answer.